# TestCafe on BrowserStack without LocalTesting?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browserstack

I am running TestCafe tests and troubleshooting BrowserStack failures related to LocalTesting (https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing). I would like to NOT use LocalTesting in my test runs.

In reading up on TestCafe's BrowserStack plugin and its source code (https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack) I am seeing that LocalTesting is used by default (ref. https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack/blob/9d45bb621cc29d1a3e78cb94d92a32a1f0dff216/src/index.js#L14O).

When I set my config to `BROWSERSTACK_NO_LOCAL="TRUE"` I am finding that tests time out at the TestCafe initial proxy URL, e.g.,
http://{host}:{port}/browser/connect/{session}

Is it possible to run TestCafe tests on BrowserStack without LocalTesting?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. To run TestCafe tests on BrowserStack without LocalTesting, you need a machine with a dedicated public IP address.
The workflow is the following:

- deploy your tested site on the machine using this way: `public-ip-address` -> `root site folder`.
- set BROWSERSTACK_NO_LOCAL="TRUE"
- set up you test's page urls as `public-ip-address`/
- install `testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack` plugin and run TestCafe with it

Comment: This isn't a viable solution for applications deployed to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I brought this question to the github project. As explained in [issue 3757](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3757#issuecomment-489620502), the application under test does not need to be deployed to a machine with a public IP address. In order to avoid BrowserStack's Local Testing, TestCafe must be run on a machine with a public IP address.